# Is there a Grails 3 profile for creating a batch application?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I'd like to create a batch application that has GORM hooked in, etc. Is there a Grails 3 profile for creating a batch (not web) application?  Is there some other pattern for using Grails/GORM in a batch context?

EDIT: None of the profiles with 'grails list-profiles' would seem to apply.  I've not had luck searching for how to do this, so maybe no one uses this pattern and uses a simple Gradle build instead.

Comment: http://gorm.grails.org/latest/hibernate/manual/index.html#outsideGrails

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the GORM outside grails, I suggest you check the latest [GORM documentation](http://gorm.grails.org/6.0.x/hibernate/manual/). You can creeate a simple groovy app and receive information from the command line and use the GORM functionality inside of it.